# Why doesn't overScrollBy() and onOverScrolled() work with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was hoping to use these methods inside my custom `RecyclerView`, but for some reason it doesn't work, and I'm not sure why...

```
@Override
protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent)     {
    return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, mOverscrollDistance, mOverscrollDistance, isTouchEvent);
}

@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
}
```

What I'm actually hoping to do is to add empty space at the beginning of the list, so that I can scroll past the first item with a set distance `mOverscrollDistance`, so if you have a better suggestion on how to achieve this then please share!

Comment: i honestly haven't tried this but did you set overscroll mode?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOverScrollMode(int)

Comment: @yigit Yep, I have set the overscroll mode to `OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS`, which I know is default but I wanted to be sure

Answer (score 0):

in the default android implemention, android will only draw glows when overscrolled:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas c) {
    super.draw(c);

    final int count = mItemDecorations.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        mItemDecorations.get(i).onDrawOver(c, this);
    }

    boolean needsInvalidate = false;
    if (mLeftGlow != null && !mLeftGlow.isFinished()) {
        final int restore = c.save();
        c.rotate(270);
        c.translate(-getHeight() + getPaddingTop(), 0);
        needsInvalidate = mLeftGlow != null && mLeftGlow.draw(c);
        c.restoreToCount(restore);
    }
    if (mTopGlow != null && !mTopGlow.isFinished()) {
        c.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
        needsInvalidate |= mTopGlow != null && mTopGlow.draw(c);
    }
    if (mRightGlow != null && !mRightGlow.isFinished()) {
        final int restore = c.save();
        final int width = getWidth();

        c.rotate(90);
        c.translate(-getPaddingTop(), -width);
        needsInvalidate |= mRightGlow != null && mRightGlow.draw(c);
        c.restoreToCount(restore);
    }
    if (mBottomGlow != null && !mBottomGlow.isFinished()) {
        final int restore = c.save();
        c.rotate(180);
        c.translate(-getWidth() + getPaddingLeft(), -getHeight()
                + getPaddingTop());
        needsInvalidate |= mBottomGlow != null && mBottomGlow.draw(c);
        c.restoreToCount(restore);
    }

    if (needsInvalidate) {
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }
}
```

if you want to have a iphone-like scroll effect, you have to do this :

1. add left margin to the first child and right child to the right child. let's say, for example , the margins are `mOverScrollSpace`
2. you need to write a method `isOverScrolled` in your own `LayoutManager` to know whether the left remain scroll space is less than  `mOverScrollSpace`
3. Then in `onTouchEvent`, when you encounter the event`ACTION_MOVE`, you write something like this

   ```
   if(isOverScrolled) {
       scrollByInternal(canScrollHorizontally ? -dx : 0,
           canScrollVertically ? -dy : 0)
   }
   else {
       scrollByInternal(canScrollHorizontally ? -dx/4 : 0,
           canScrollVertically ? -dy/4 : 0)
   }
   ```